# Word Time entry table

Tags: microsoft-word, vba, microsoft-word-365

I am making a timesheet for my employer, and it needs to be in a Word table.
Rows contain the following cells, going across:
Start Time (clock time) / Lunch Duration (# minutes) / End Time (Clock Time) / Daily Hours (Total hours and minutes).
I have been able to come up with a formula that automatically sums the Daily Hours on each row as I type it.
{=sum(f3,f4,f5,f6,f7,f8,f9,f10)# "0.00" }

I would like to have the Daily Hours column automatically populate as data is entered on the Time End cell, and then have this number be added in to the sum at the bottom.  So for example, on the first row I enter 8:30 as the start time, 30 as the minutes for lunch, 17:00 as the end time, and when I finish typing 17:00 and tab out of that cell, have Daily Hours now show 8.00 for total hours, and have that value auto show up in the sum at the bottom as well.

I think what is confusing me is trying to mix clock time, and numeric hours and minutes.

All assistance appreciated.

Zane

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Some diagrams of your data would help us understand your question. See [Format Text as a Table](https://www.tablesgenerator.com/text_tables) for a web utility that will help you to create a nice data table you can paste into your question.

Comment: Word can easily handle Hours and decimal parts of hours, hours and minutes is tougher. If your boss is OK with it, Excel would handle this much more easily than Word does. You can easily incorporate an Excel table into a Word document. If Excel can't be used, take a look at the switches portion of my page on Date fields. http://addbalance.com/word/datefields1.htm#PageStart

Comment: Take a look at Paul Edstein's Date Calculation Tutorial http://www.msofficeforums.com/word/38719-microsoft-word-date-calculation-tutorial.html. First, read all the introductory material. On Page 15 you will see fields for adding or subtracting time.

Comment: Note that this is not a code-writing service. https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask